# (Discord bot 1.0 c#) How to make a new class and add cmds?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Hello there Stackoverflow! (first time posting here so plz be nice :P)

So, I've decided to make a discord bot 1.0 in c# (i'm learning c# atm) and I have gotten in to a problem and i'm not sure how to fix it..

So, to describe what i'm trying to do is following.

I'm trying to make it so i can have different classes for x commands such as .say etc instead of having em all in the "commands" one below so its a bit easier to work with.

I got these working three scripts but cant get the fourth to work

//Startup

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Discord.Commands;

namespace MyBot
{
public class Program
{
    // Convert our sync main to an async main.
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        new Program().Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    private DiscordSocketClient client;
    private CommandHandler handler;

    public async Task Start()
    {
        // Define the DiscordSocketClient
        client = new DiscordSocketClient();

        var token = "Censored";

        // Login and connect to Discord.
        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
        await client.StartAsync();

        var map = new DependencyMap();
        map.Add(client);

        handler = new CommandHandler();
        await handler.Install(map);

        // Block this program until it is closed.
        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
}
```

//My command handler

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;

namespace MyBot
{
public class CommandHandler
{
    private CommandService commands;
    private DiscordSocketClient client;
    private IDependencyMap map;

    public async Task Install(IDependencyMap _map)
    {
        // Create Command Service, inject it into Dependency Map
        client = _map.Get<DiscordSocketClient>();
        commands = new CommandService();
        _map.Add(commands);
        map = _map;

        await commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

        client.MessageReceived += HandleCommand;
    }

    public async Task HandleCommand(SocketMessage parameterMessage)
    {
        // Don't handle the command if it is a system message
        var message = parameterMessage as SocketUserMessage;
        if (message == null) return;

        // Mark where the prefix ends and the command begins
        int argPos = 0;
        // Determine if the message has a valid prefix, adjust argPos 
        if (!(message.HasMentionPrefix(client.CurrentUser, ref argPos) || message.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos))) return;

        // Create a Command Context
        var context = new CommandContext(client, message);
        // Execute the Command, store the result
        var result = await commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, map);

        // If the command failed, notify the user
        if (!result.IsSuccess)
            await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"**Error:** {result.ErrorReason}");
    }
}
}
```

//Commands

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyBot.Modules.Public
{
public class PublicModule : ModuleBase
{
    [Command("invite")]
    [Summary("Returns the OAuth2 Invite URL of the bot")]
    public async Task Invite()
    {
        var application = await Context.Client.GetApplicationInfoAsync();
        await ReplyAsync(
            $"A user with `MANAGE_SERVER` can invite me to your server here: <https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={application.Id}&scope=bot>");
    }

    [Command("leave")]
    [Summary("Instructs the bot to leave this Guild.")]
    [RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageGuild)]
    public async Task Leave()
    {
        if (Context.Guild == null) { await ReplyAsync("This command can only be ran in a server."); return; }
        await ReplyAsync("Leaving~");
        await Context.Guild.LeaveAsync();
    }
}
}
```

//This is the one i want to work but i only get "Unknown command" as error?

```
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyBot.Modules.Public
{
class test : ModuleBase
{
    [Command("say")]
    [Alias("echo")]
    [Summary("Echos the provided input")]
    public async Task Say([Remainder] string input)
    {
        await ReplyAsync(input);
    }
}
}
```

If you know what i do wrong please tell me or reefer me to some info about the problem and i can try fix it :)
Thanks in advance!
PS, im sorry if there is a dupe of this question but i don't know what to search for to find it

EDIT
I've been told to "Pit the metohds (cmds) in the class" but how would i go around todo that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is following

Add Public before the class {name}so it would be

```
namespace MyBot.Modules.Public
{
   **Public** class test : ModuleBase
{
    [Command("say")]
    [Alias("echo")]
    [Summary("Echos the provided input")]
    public async Task Say([Remainder] string input)
    {
        await ReplyAsync(input);
    }
}
```

}